# Audio driver base address, DMA and IRQ

Tags: linux, audio, driver, hardware

In the old days you would look at finding the base addr, DMA and IRQ to communicate with a device. I'm kinda looking for the equiviant.

I'm looking to communicate directly with an audio device, not through a driver, in Linux. Time isn't an issue, but I am struggling to find the information that I need and I know there is a possibility of needing a lot of code, that's fine.

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction to achieving this.

Thankyou very much.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of a use case for this...

Comment: Does that effect if an answer can be given?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I was aware you couldn't use IRQs or DMA if you're in a user-mode process from linux and [this guide](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/text/IO-Port-Programming) (heading 3) seems to confirm that, however after checking I managed to find [this Linux driver (udmabuf)](https://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf) that lets you access DMA buffers through the user space; maybe this is what you are looking for?

Otherwise I would mabye try and write a similar, but more customized version of [(udmabuf)](https://github.com/ikwzm/udmabuf), specific to your purpose.

I'm not sure entirely what you are planning on using it for, but the first thing I would look for is building a driver for what you wanted to do ([here's how to get started for ALSA](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/sound/kernel-api/writing-an-alsa-driver.html) just as an example). At least to communicate at this level, unless you wanted to do some of your own OS development? (I think this would be the way in the end if you really couldn't use drivers for whatever purpose)

Comment: The idea is that I want to play around with DOS in my spare time. First I need to write something that will play in a standard OS, and then I can begin rewriting it for DOS. Any additional pointers would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I feel bad by answering this myself, WoodyDev, thankyou for pointing me in the right direction.

You are right, a driver is the best way to go.

The best solution is to read the PCI Address Space, the first 64 bytes contain all the data needed.

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/linux-device-drivers/0596000081/ch15.html